# configure environments with restify

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, restify

I'm familiar with gulp and the ability to have a distinct configuration for each environment within a single configuration file. That way running `gulp dev` would allow you to start your server with the configuration of your dev environment, `gulp staging` for your staging and `gulp prod` fro production.

I'm now looking at restify and am trying to determine if something similar can be done with it. I've tried researching this online and haven't found anything meaningful. Is this possible and if so could somebody provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**dotenv**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package to load different configuration file. For example

1. **.env.dev** For **Development environment**
2. **.env.prod** for **Production environment**
3. **.env.test** for **Testing environment**

   you can import file according to **NODE_ENV** var
   or you can simply add all configuration variable in one file for example

   **.conf.env** and import it.